# How do I get the unique values of a list in bash preserving order and keep the last value for each unique?

Tags: bash

I have a list in bash that can have repeated values in it. I would like to remove duplicates and get a list with only the unique values in it. Order must be preserved and the last occurrence of the unique values is the one I wish to keep.

For example, if I have this list:

```
A=( D B A C D )
```

I'm looking for this:

```
result=( B A C D )
```

I've seen solutions for this when the data is a list in a file, but I'd prefer to keep the list in-memory without jumping through any hoops.

I think I can use an associative array and loop through the list adding the entries as keys in the array and then just dump the keys into the unique list but I'm not an expert with associative arrays across platforms -- do they sort themselves on key value sort of like a lot of C++ STL containers do or do they preserve the order of insertion regardless of key values?

I'd like to avoid a reliance on associative arrays though, because not all systems I may need to run on have bash 4.x or higher... some will be bash 3.x...

Any help would be great.

Comment: use `awk` for assoc arrays. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Associative Arrays**

You can do it with indexed arrays by using an intermediate indexed array to hold unique values from `A`. This requires a nested loop over values stored in `c[]` for each element of `A`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a result   # declare result indexed array
declare -a c        # declare temp intermediate indexed array

A=( D B A C D )     # original with duplicates

## loop decending over A, reset found flag, loop over c, if present continue,
#  otherwise store A at index in c
for ((i = $((${#A[@]}-1)); i >= 0; i--)); do 
    found=0;
    for j in ${c[@]}; do
        [ "$j" = "${A[i]}" ] && { found=1; break; }
    done
    [ "$found" -eq '1' ] && continue
    c[i]=${A[i]}
done

## loop over c testing if index for A exists, add from c to result
for ((i = 0; i < ${#A[@]}; i++)); do 
    [ "${c[i]}" ] && result+=(${c[i]})
done

declare -p result   # output result
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash lastuniqindexed.sh
declare -a result='([0]="B" [1]="A" [2]="C" [3]="D")'
```

**Using Associative Arrays with BASH_VERSION Test**

You can do it with a combination of indexed and associative arrays making only a single pass though each array. You use an associative array `B` keyed with the value of `A` using `B` as a *frequency array* indicating whether an element of `A` has been seen. You then store the element of `A` in a temporary indexed array `c[]` so that the unique values can be added to `result` preserving the original order.

You can address whether associative array functionality is present with a bash version test at the beginning, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

case $BASH_VERSION in 
    ## empty or beginning with 1, 2, 3
    ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 needed" >&2
    exit 1;;
esac

declare -A B        # declare associative array
declare -a result   # declare indexed array

A=( D B A C D )     # original with duplicates

## loop decending over A, if B[A] doesn't exist, set B[A]=1, store in c[]
for ((i = $((${#A[@]}-1)); i >= 0; i--)); do 
    [ -n "${B[${A[i]}]}" ] || { B[${A[i]}]=1; c[i]=${A[i]};}
done

## loop over c testing if index for A exists, add from c to result
for ((i = 0; i < ${#A[@]}; i++)); do 
    [ "${c[i]}" ] && result+=(${c[i]})
done

declare -p result   # output result
```

Without the use of associative arrays, the nested loops looping over the original checking against each entry in `c[]` will be much less efficient as the size of the array grows.

**Example Use/Output**

```
 $ bash lastuniq.sh
declare -a result='([0]="B" [1]="A" [2]="C" [3]="D")'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.